¿Cuando es necesario usar clausula "OF" al crear clases en Visual Basic?
Estoy siguiendo la documentacion de visual basic y tratando de entender cuando se usan ciertas clausulas. En este caso la clasula "OF" al momento de crear una clase. Entiendo que sirve para poder declarar los tipos de objetos dentro de la clase (En este caso clases que implementan Interfaces)
por ejemplo :
Namespace ModulosIniciales
Public Class ClaseBasicaOF(Of ClaseA As InterfaceBasica, ClaseB As InterfaceBasica)
    
    Public Sub MetodoGenerico(ByVal A As ClaseA, ByVal B As ClaseB)
        A.EscribirConsola()
        B.EscribirPersonalizado("Hola Mundo")
    End Sub
End Class

Finalmente para ejecutarlo lo invoco asi en el main(La clase A y B son clases que implementan la interface "InterfaceBasica")
    Private Sub Probando_ClaseTipeOf()
        Dim A As New ClaseImplementador(1, 2, "TEXTOA")
        Dim B As New ClaseImplementador(3, 4, "TEXTOB")
        Dim InstanciaClaseBasicaOF As New ClaseBasicaOF(Of ClaseImplementador, ClaseImplementador)
        InstanciaClaseBasicaOF.MetodoGenerico(A, B)
    End Sub

Con esto funciona sin problemas, pero veo que hay otra forma de ejecutar los mismo y es el siguiente codigo ( en este caso quito el "Of" de la clase e indico directamente en el procedimiento que las variables deben ser clases que implementen interfaces)
Namespace ModulosIniciales
Public Class ClaseBasicaOF
    Public Sub MetodoGenerico(ByVal A As InterfaceBasica, ByVal B As InterfaceBasica)
        A.EscribirConsola()
        B.EscribirPersonalizado("Hola Mundo")
    End Sub
End Class

End Namespace
Y para implementarlo en el main realizo lo siguiente
    Private Sub Probando_ClaseTipeOf()
        Dim A As New ClaseImplementador(1, 2, "TEXTOA")
        Dim B As New ClaseImplementador(3, 4, "TEXTOB")
        Dim InstanciaClaseBasicaOF As New ClaseBasicaOF
        InstanciaClaseBasicaOF.MetodoGenerico(A, B)
    End Sub

Ambos caminos me dan el  mismo resultado, por lo que quisiera saber en casos casos el uso de la clausula "Of" es necesario o si es una expresion que no tiene mucho uso en visual basic.

No puedo arreglar "End Namespace" en tu segundo ejemplo porque la solución tiene menos de 6 caracteres. grrrrr.

Si, ignorar el name space que esta ahi de mas :c

El uso de "of" en una clase  se puede interpretar como "el avisar que vas a pasar un parametro, pero que no esta definido de que tipo sera" y esto solo se sabra  durante la instanciacion de la clase.
Ahora hay que saber que esta misma indefinición limitara lo que puedes hacer con los parametros que usemos, miremos el siguiente ejemplo :
    Public Class ClaseBasicaOF_2(Of ClaseA, ClaseB)
    Public Sub MetodoPrueba(ByVal A As ClaseA, ByVal B As ClaseB)
        Console.WriteLine(A.GetHashCode)
        Console.WriteLine(B.GetType)

    End Sub
    End Class

Aqui estamos comunicando que A y B son de un tipo desconocido , por lo que los metodos que podemos usar en estos son limitado ( solo le podemos aplicar metodos genericos de VB como GetType, getHashCode, ToString, etc)
Luego para invocarlo en el main seria de la siguiente manera
   Dim A As New ClaseBasica(1)
   Dim B As New ClaseBasica(2)
   Dim x As New ClaseBasicaOF_2(Of ClaseBasica, ClaseBasica)
   x.MetodoPrueba(A, B)

ClaseBasica es cualquier clase, creamos la instancia x ahora si indicando de que tipo van a ser los parametros declarados ( mencionar que para este ejemplo son de tipo ClaseBasica, pero podrian ser integer, String, double etc)
El resultado por consola seria el siguiente (El codigo has de la ClaseA y el nombre completo de la clase B)

Por ultimo mencionar que esto parece mas aprovechable con el uso de interfaces. Esto debido a que el tipo del parametro seguira siendo indefinido ,pero podemos tener la certeza que debe implementar un interface.
Por ejemplo aqui "ClaseA" y "ClaseB" no se sabe que tipo de objetos son , pero lo que si es obligatorio es que implementen la interface "InterfaceBasica" y por ello sus metodos . Con esto ya no estamos limitados a los metodos de VB si no que podemos invocar a los de la interface como "EscribirConsola" y "EscribirConsolaPersonalizado" ( Los cuales no tenemos la mas remota idea que hacen , pero no importa porque su funcionamiento se define en la clases no la interface)
Public Class ClaseBasicaOF_Inter(Of ClaseA As InterfaceBasica, ClaseB As 
InterfaceBasica)
Public Sub MetodoPrueba_Inter(ByVal A As ClaseA, ByVal B As ClaseB)
    A.EscribirConsola()
    B.EscribirConsola()
End Sub
End Class

Finalmente en el metodo principal se puede llamar de la siguiente manera.(ClaseImplementadora1 y ClaseImplementadora2 son cualquier clase que implemente la interface)
Dim A As New ClaseImplementador1(1, 2, "TEXTOA")
Dim B As New ClaseImplementador2(3, 4, "TEXTOB")
Dim InstanciaClaseBasicaOF_Inter As New ClaseBasicaOF_Inter(Of 
ClaseImplementador, ClaseImplementador)
InstanciaClaseBasicaOF_Inter.MetodoPrueba_Inter(A, B)

Esto ejecutara el metodo "escribir consola" de A y "escribir consola" de B ( los cuales podrian realizar actividades totalmente distintas teniendo el mismo nombre debido a como funciona una interface)
En resumen el uso de "Of"  seria adecuado cuando por algún motivo  quieres dar un amplio rango de posibles tipos a  los  atributos   , si tus atributos van a ser ser casi siempre del tipo esperado no habria necesidad de usar ello. Por otro lado considerar su uso si esperas clases que implementan interfaces.
Gracias a Peter M por su respuesta que me ayudo a terminar de entender esto.

Creo que estas mezclando dos ideas en tu código, pero en este caso (por accidente) cada de unos devuelve la misma resulta que quieres.
Tu primero exjemplo  usa "Of" para indicar que "ClaseBasicaOF" es una clase genérica que usa qualquier tipo que implementa la interfaz "InterfaceBasica".  Y cuando creas la instancia de "ClaseBasicaOF" como "InstanciaClaseBasicaOF" tu has definido que A y B tienan que ser el tipo de clase "ClaseImplementador".  Cuando llamas MetodoGenerico(), los parameteros tienen que ser del tipo "ClaseImplementador"
En tu secondo exjemplo, clase "ClaseBasicaOF" es una clase simple (y no es de genérico).  En esta clase la subrutina "MetodoGenerico" toma dos parametos que implementan  la interfaz "InterfaceBasica",  y cada de los dos pueden ser cualquier tipa de clase siempre y cuando implementar esa interfaz.  Entonces, cuando llamas MetodoGenerico(), las clases solo tienen que implementar la interfaz, y no tienen que ser del tipo "ClaseImplementador". (Tengas en cuenta que aunque en este caso la subroutina se llama  "MetodoGenerico", no es una subrutina genérica)
Entonces, "Of" se usa para definar objectos que son genérico.  Tu primero ejemplo es un ejemplo de genéricos, pero tu sungundo no es.
Por un ejemplo muy simples de genéricos, por favor ver aquí
Si utiliza muchos genéricos, depende del tipo de código que esté escribiendo.
